# Pandas conditional sum of column

Tags: pandas, sum, conditional-statements

New to pandas & trying to do something quite simple which is to sum revenue if year and date conditions are met:

```
transactions['date_new'] = pd.to_datetime(transactions.date, format="%d.%m.%Y")
transactions['revenue'] = transactions.item_price * transactions.item_cnt_day
print(transactions.head(5))
temp = transactions.loc[(transactions.date_new.dt.year == 14) & (transactions.date_new.dt.month == 9), transactions.revenue].sum()
```

But then I get a key error that look like this:
KeyError: 'None of [0           999.00\n1           899.00\n2          -899.00\n3

Comment: can you try `transactions.loc[(transactions.date_new.dt.year == 2014) & (transactions.date_new.dt.month == 9), transactions.revenue].sum()` , `dt.year` returns a full year and not an abbreviated version. Might be that is the issue, not sure though. It is better to post a sample dataframe showing the problem

Comment: yeah that worked; add to chance to "revenue" as well instead of transactions.revenue